# Changing the Sharepoint farm admin account

Tags: administration

What are the drawbacks of changing the farm admin account in SharePoint 2010 installation. OR is it possible to change the farm admin account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Shankar ,

Considering the impact on change of the farm administrator account , here are the breakup of things that will need your attention:

1. If the farm admin account is also used as service account for SharePoint , you are looking for trouble.
2. If the farm admin account is also used as SQL Service account , you are looking for trouble.
3. IF the farm admin account is used for running any active application pool on IIS, this can be a problem.
4. Also for deploying solutions you must be a farm administrator.
5. Farm administrator also happens to be in the local administrator group of all the servers in the database.
6. Farm administrator also has db_creator , db_owner rights on all WSS Content databases.

The above six points are imperative for a check when adding/removing a new farm administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about drawbacks but you can change the admin on Farm (you should be admin on the farm to do this).

Login to Server, then go to Programs > Microsoft Share Point 2010 Products > SharePoint 2010 Central Administration.

Once you logged in Central Admin site go to Site Actions > Site Settings  >  People and Groups - Farm Administrators

From here you can add/remove admin from the farm.

Comment: Thanks! but i am more concerned about the impact it might have on the system.